# Parsing XML Node Values For Export To CSV

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to get the value of "location path = ", "allowUnlisted", and all of the IP addresses so I can export them to csv.

Example of XML

```
<configuration> 
 <location path="Example/5192_proxy">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.100.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.48.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.100.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="192.168.63.97" subnetMask="255.255.255.224" allowed="true" />
                </ipSecurity>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <location path="Example/3796_Proxy">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                    <add ipAddress="192.168.30.52" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.48.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" allowed="true" />
                </ipSecurity>   
               </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

This is what I have so far, it's throwing multiple numbers in the "ExampleCLient" field

```
$snippet.configuration.location."system.WebServer".security.ipSecurity |select @{L="ExampleClient";E={$snippet.configuration.location.path}}, allowUnlisted, add -ExpandProperty add
```

Ultimately I would like it to read like

```
ExampleClient   AllowUnlisted  IPAddress
Example/5192       False       10.10.100.0
Example/5192       False       10.10.48.0
...
Example/3796_Proxy False       192.168.30.52
```

Edit:

This is working somewhat, I think I got it!

```
[xml]$xml = (Get-Content .\Sample.xml)
$finum = $($xml.configuration.location.path)
FOREACH ($fi in $finum) 
 {
  $xml.configuration.location."system.webServer".security.ipSecurity |select allowUnlisted, add -ExpandProperty add |select @{L="FI";E={$fi}}, allowunlisted, ipaddress, subnetmask
 }
```

Comment: Your post appears to contain no question - what is it you need help with, where are you stuck? :)

Comment: I'm stuck on getting the output in the format I want it in.  This "$snippet.configuration.location."system.WebServer".security.ipSecurity |select @{L="ExampleClient";E={$snippet.configuration.location.path}}, allowUnlisted, add -ExpandProperty add" gets me most of the way there.  This code places all of the exampleclients into the example client field instead of just one client.

Comment: II think I got it, will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like below:

```
[xml]$snippet = @"
<configuration> 
 <location path="Example/5192_proxy">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.100.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.48.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.100.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="192.168.63.97" subnetMask="255.255.255.224" allowed="true" />
                </ipSecurity>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <location path="Example/3796_Proxy">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                    <add ipAddress="192.168.30.52" allowed="true" />
                    <add ipAddress="10.10.48.0" subnetMask="255.255.240.0" allowed="true" />
                </ipSecurity>   
               </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
"@

$result = $snippet.configuration.location | ForEach-Object {
    $client        = $_.path
    $allowUnlisted = $_.'system.WebServer'.security.ipSecurity.allowUnlisted
    foreach ($ip in $_.'system.WebServer'.security.ipSecurity.add.ipAddress) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ExampleClient = $client 
            AllowUnlisted = $allowUnlisted
            IPAddress     = $ip
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\config.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

> ```
> ExampleClient      AllowUnlisted IPAddress    
> -------------      ------------- ---------    
> Example/5192_proxy false         10.10.100.0  
> Example/5192_proxy false         10.10.48.0   
> Example/5192_proxy false         10.10.100.0  
> Example/5192_proxy false         192.168.63.97
> Example/3796_Proxy false         192.168.30.52
> Example/3796_Proxy false         10.10.48.0
> ```

---

As per your comment, you would also like to include the subnetmask, the inner foreach loop needs to be changed a little:

```
$result = $snippet.configuration.location | ForEach-Object {
    $client        = $_.path
    $allowUnlisted = $_.'system.WebServer'.security.ipSecurity.allowUnlisted
    foreach ($item in $_.'system.WebServer'.security.ipSecurity.add) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ExampleClient = $client 
            AllowUnlisted = $allowUnlisted
            IPAddress     = $item.ipAddress
            SubnetMask    = $item.subnetMask
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> ```
> ExampleClient      AllowUnlisted IPAddress     SubnetMask     
> -------------      ------------- ---------     ----------     
> Example/5192_proxy false         10.10.100.0   255.255.252.0  
> Example/5192_proxy false         10.10.48.0    255.255.240.0  
> Example/5192_proxy false         10.10.100.0   255.255.252.0  
> Example/5192_proxy false         192.168.63.97 255.255.255.224
> Example/3796_Proxy false         192.168.30.52                
> Example/3796_Proxy false         10.10.48.0    255.255.240.0
> ```

Comment: Could you modify to grab the subnet as well?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [an XPath query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation) or 3!

In the below example, we:

1. Locate any `<add ipAddress="...">` nodes in the document
   `//add[@ipAddress]`
2. Select the "ExampleClient" value from the first `<location>` ancestor 
   `./ancestor::location`
3. Select the "AllowUnlisted" value similarly from the first `<ipSecurity>` ancestor
   `./ancestor::ipSecurity`

```bsh
$ipNodes = $snippet.SelectNodes('//add[@ipAddress]')

$ipNodes |Select-Object @{Name='ExampleClient';E={$_.SelectSingleNode('./ancestor::location').path}},@{Name='AllowUnlisted';E={[bool]::Parse($_.SelectSingleNode('./ancestor::ipSecurity').allowUnlisted)}},ipAddress
```